# Display all Dict in New windows GUI using Label tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am New to python and going though few online training.I couldn't get any close related to below question.

I am using tkinter GUI

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
trainings = {"title":"Python Training Course for Beginners",
                     "location":"Frankfurt",
                     "ID": 111,"title":"Intermediate Python Training",
                     "location":"Berlin",
                     "ID": 133,"title":"Python Text Processing Course",
                     "location":"Mdsgtd",
                     "ID": 122}

  for key in trainings.keys():
   x = trainings.get(key)
   print x


  Label(root, text = x ).pack()
  mainloop()
```

Getting output only:`122`

But I am expecting result should be display in GUI Label:

```
{'ID': 111, 'location': 'Frankfurt', 'title': 'Python Training Course for Beginners'}
{'ID': 122, 'location': 'Mdsgtd', 'title': 'Python Text Processing Course'}
{'ID': 133, 'location': 'Berlin', 'title': 'Intermediate Python Training'}
```

Can I used inside the function label as in below code: which is not working:

```
def OnButtonClick(self):
    self.top= Toplevel()
    self.top.title("Read Data Service Menu Item")
    self.topdata = {'parakeet': ['fly', 'bird'], 'dog': 'animal', 'cat': 'feline'}
    for key in self.topdata.keys():
               x = self.topdata.get(key)

    self.topL2 = Label(self.top, text = key).pack()

    self.top.resizable(1,0)
    self.top.transient(self)
    self.B1.config(state = 'normal') #disable/normal

    self.topButton = Button(self.top, text = 'Close', command = self.OnChildClose)
    self.topButton.pack()
```

Comment: you use keys multiple times in your dictionary - you shouldn't do this!

Comment: the indentation does that `Label(root, text = x ).pack()` is only called with the last value of `x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues at present, as noted in the comments. Firstly, you should change your `trainings` dictionary to be *a list of dictionaries* to let you store the relevant information for each course in turn.

Assuming you want to show a different label for the information relating to each course, the following should work:

```
from Tkinter import *

courses = [{"title": "Python Training Course for Beginners",
            "location": "Frankfurt",
            "ID": 111},
           {"title": "Intermediate Python Training",
            "location": "Berlin",
            "ID": 133},
           {"title": "Python Text Processing Course",
            "location": "Mdsgtd",
            "ID": 122}]


root = Tk()

for course in courses:
    temp_text = '{0} ({1}) - {2}'.format(course['title'], course['ID'], course['location'])
    Label(root, text=temp_text).pack()

mainloop()
```

We use string formatting to create a nicely-written output, of the course name followed by its ID in brackets, then the location of the course after a dash.

What is critical here is that we want to create a `Label` widget for every course - hence, we add the new `Label` within our for loop to ensure this happens.

Comment: If my ID is in HEX like 0x111, 0x122. Then How can I display same hex in label

Comment: @BharatKathari replace `course['id']` with `int(course['ID'], 0)` in the line where `temp_text` is created

Comment: Its working, Now I want to display in label like below without changing the courses list: 1. Python Training Course for Beginners Frankfurt 111, 2. Intermediate Python Training 222....Basically adding sl. number at beginning